# 1.4 Commons-DBCP being brought in instead of 1.3

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management, apache-commons-dbcp

I have a strange situation. In jar A, I explicitly bring in version 1.3 of commons-dbcp. In jar B, I have a dependency on jar A. However, when I bring in the jar A dependency in jar B, my maven dependency hierarchy shows that jar B is now using 1.4. If I remove that dependency, commons-dbcp is gone from my maven dependency hierarchy so I feel certain it's not being pulled in elsewhere. And when I'm in jar A's maven dependency hierarchy, it only shows 1.3.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven automatically determines the version to bring in for transitive dependencies.  You may have more than one dependency on commons-dbcp (perhaps you're test wouldn't show it if they are in different scope).  Use the [Maven dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) via `mvn dependency:tree` to see the other dependencies.

Comment: I only have the one dependency on commons-dbcp according to that.

Comment: You should expand your question details.  Show your pom.  Show output from dependency:tree etc.  The only time I've ever encountered mvn pulling in a different version than the one requested is due to transitive dependencies.  I suppose it might happen if you have it doubly defined - Once in dependcyManagement section and once again in dependencies?

Comment: After looking again at things, I realized the problem and why it didn't show up in the previous jar or via the dependency tree. The dbcp version was being set in a parent pom that our team uses and that's what was overriding it. You made me think of that to investigate so thank you.